# reledmac: \eledsection* in Header?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, reledmac, reledpar

A simple question: Is it possible to use the \eledsection* in the Header as you would e.g. with KOMA's \addsec or as it would appear with a numbered section (\eledsection)? Thanks for any help!

```
\documentclass[paper=b5,fontsize=12pt,twoside=semi]{scrbook}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{twocol}
\linenummargin{inner}
\firstlinenum{5}
\linenumincrement{5}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\eledsection*{INCIPIT ORDO ANTIPHONARII PER ANNI CIRCULUM}
\pend 
\pstart 
(25r) Secundum sex aetates 
\pend   
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: \eledesection* is based on \section*. So, if \section* does not produce an header, it won't. However, maybe scrbook have setting to add that in header (and don't know Komascript). Also you could add \sectionmark manually.

Comment: I'd suggest using \markleft, \markright or \markboth commands. KOMA script provides a command addsec{} which produces a columntitle but avoids numbering. But it shouldn't be used with reledmacs numbered context.

Comment: thanks! \pstart \eledsection*{\markright{TEXT}<TEXT>}\pend does the job. But now I wondered how I could use this header on every page even though I use the option twoside?

Comment: You could use `\newcommand*\markdouble[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}` and `\eledsection*{\markdouble{TEXT}TEXT}` or you could load `\package{scrlayer-scrpage}` and use `\ohead{\rightmark}`.